# How to capture a word between two hyphens in python with regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract words that are between two hyphens or between one hyphen and nothing. But let's say I am not supposed to know the words before/between/after the hyphens.
I've tried with re.search using regex pattern. When using website to test regex the captured groups are not the same in python.

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['tumPar-PredCorr', 'lung-Med-Pred', 'liver-t1flair-FromMed', 'kidney-t1ce-Pred', 'tumMed-Pred']})
```

The result in a new column should be : PredCorr, Med, t1flair, t1ce, Pred

With the following code in python :

```
def extract_signals(row):
    if row!="":
        return re.search(r"([-^]\w+)",row).group()

df["signals"]= df["col1"].apply(extract_signals)
```

I get almost the result because I have -PredCorr, -Med, -t1flair, -t1ce, -Pred
So it would be great to not have the hyphen before those words.
Note that those patterns for regex give the same results in python too : ([-]\w+) or (-\w+)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['signals'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'-([^-]+)(?:-|$)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6H8MKS/1). The regex matches

- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `-`
- `(?:-|$)` - either a `-` or end of string.

Python test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['tumPar-PredCorr', 'lung-Med-Pred', 'liver-t1flair-FromMed', 'kidney-t1ce-Pred', 'tumMed-Pred']})
>>> df['col1'].str.extract(r'-([^-]+)(?:-|$)')
          0
0  PredCorr
1       Med
2   t1flair
3      t1ce
4      Pred
```